# React Native , animated negative rotation

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I'm using a pan responder to capture user's swipe movement, downward or upward and upon that, I rotate a circle :

if positive :

```
 Animated.decay(animation, {velocity: fingerVelocity}).start();
```

if negative :

```
 Animated.decay(animationNegative, {velocity: fingerVelocity}).start();
```

and then I use above to rotate two different circles :

```
  const animationStyle = animation.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 300],
        outputRange: ["0deg", "360deg"],
        extrapolate: 'identity'
    });

  const animationNegativeStyle = animationNegative.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 300],
        outputRange: ["0deg", "-360deg"],
        extrapolate: 'identity'
    });
```

For the `positive` it works fine, but for the negative, it rotates counter-clockwise 350deg and then rotates clockwise .

NOTE : The reason I'm using `identity` is because the animation type is a `decay` and I don't know what the value could be at that time, and the velocity of the `decay` animation depends on the velocity of the user's swipe.

So when I log the values, it goes like this for negative :

`value       interpolatedValue 
0           -360
1           -359
2           -358
3           -357
....
360         0
361         1
362         2 
....`

I know the problem is the `identity`, but how do fix it ?

Is this even possible with `Animated` api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is the solution.

your normal decay :

```
Animated.decay(animation, {velocity: fingerVelocity}).start();
```

now the values are increasing, which is not what you want, you want them to decrease

```
 const animationNegative = Animated.multiply(animationNegative, -1);

 const animationNegativeStyle = animationNegative.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ["0deg", "1deg"], // we don't care, we just want the identity to kick in and use the value as is
        extrapolate: 'identity'
    });
```

Comment: oh damn, easy, how come I didn't think of it, damn

Answer (score 1):

```
 const animationNegativeStyle = animationNegative.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 300],
        outputRange: ["360deg", "0deg"],
        extrapolate: 'identity'
    });
```

I'm not sure if this solution will work but at least can you try it and share results of it

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure it won't work. You're clearly going from 360deg to 0 degrees in a positive direction.

Comment: Correct, but when `identity` kicks in, the actual value will be used, and the actual value is always positive because of decay